# Datatables in a form of grid using ajax based pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to show a datatable in a grid with an ajax based pagination and searching(auto-complete) also based on ajax.I want to achieve the grid shown in an image below through datatables. Is it possible? I have searched about it but could not find any solution so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! [image]

Comment: Do you want to show a datatable under the image?

Comment: @azizsagi i want to show an image also in a datatable, the whole datatable in gridview or bind datatable to some grid view similar to this one. Is it possible?

Comment: similar to which one?

Comment: @azizsagi similiar to the image

Comment: @Tabby, so your question is "as displayed in image is possible using datatable or not? " right?

Comment: @azizsagi yes, right